# How to add /amp in All pages using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please help me with this, I want to add `/amp` in every URL, on all devices. 
like this: `https://example.com/hell-world/amp`

I tried adding this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/amp$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

But nothing changes.

This the code of .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/amp$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hello Chris, welcome to so. I checked you regex, it's like OK. Have you control over your apache2 server, with config file like /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, you might have some AllowOverride None, disabling .htaccess.

Comment: My VPS has Apache 4 what to do?

Comment: Hello, according to  Wikipedia, https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server, the last stable apache server is 2.4.41. You should  be in apache2. You can search file under /etc/apache2 a file like apache.conf, and check AllowOverride directive.